# R: use cochran.test in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to use the cochran.test function from the package outliers in a for loop so that I can loop through a number of variables in the formula argument of the function:

```
library(outliers)

# generating test data
data <- 
data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),c(1,2,3,1,2,4),c(1,2,3,1,2,4),c(1,2,3,1,2,4))
colnames(data) <- c("group", "firstvar", "secondvar", "thirdvar")
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
variables <- c("firstvar", "secondvar", "thirdvar")

# works without loop
cochran.test(firstvar~group,data)

# doesn't work in a loop
for (i in variables) {
  cochran.test(i~group,data)
}
```

The first example works fine, the loop doesn't. Instead I get the following error:

```
Error in tapply(data[[bn[1]]], by.factor, var) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.formula` to define the desired y~x formula inside a loop using `i` as variable:

```
library(outliers)

# generating test data
data <- 
  data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),c(1,2,3,1,2,4),c(1,2,3,1,2,4),c(1,2,3,1,2,4))
colnames(data) <- c("group", "firstvar", "secondvar", "thirdvar")
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
variables <- c("firstvar", "secondvar", "thirdvar")

# works in a loop
for (i in variables) {
  print(cochran.test(as.formula(paste(i,'~group')),data))
}

##   Cochran test for outlying variance
## 
## data:  as.formula(paste(i, "~group"))
## C = 0.7, df = 3, k = 2, p-value = 0.6
## alternative hypothesis: Group 2 has outlying variance
## sample estimates:
##        1        2 
## 1.000000 2.333333 
## 
## 
##  Cochran test for outlying variance
## 
## data:  as.formula(paste(i, "~group"))
## C = 0.7, df = 3, k = 2, p-value = 0.6
## alternative hypothesis: Group 2 has outlying variance
## sample estimates:
##        1        2 
## 1.000000 2.333333 
## 
## 
##  Cochran test for outlying variance
## 
## data:  as.formula(paste(i, "~group"))
## C = 0.7, df = 3, k = 2, p-value = 0.6
## alternative hypothesis: Group 2 has outlying variance
## sample estimates:
##        1        2 
## 1.000000 2.333333
```